# Java WS Synchronize information process?

Tags: java, web-services

I’m new with the w son java and I have checked several tutorials that describe the process to create and expose a ws.  But I have a main concern referred to the concurrence of the methods that the ws may call at the same time from different client petitions. I see some example in which the authors use the “Synchronize” but Im not sure this is the best way to duet.  I will appreciate if someone can refer me to some article that may describe the correct procedure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Methods and blocks can be declared synchronized if two or more threads may try to call them simultaneously. If the method or block is synchronized, only one thread may "control" it at a time--all other threads that try to call it will block until they're given control.

Here are some examples:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm
- http://careerride.com/Java-what-is-synchronization.aspx